# The documentation suggests that apache's DocumentRoot is /var/www but my test shows it to be /var/www/html. Which is it?

Tags: apache2

The documentation suggests that apache's DocumentRoot is `/var/www`  but my test shows it to be `/var/www/html`   Which is it?

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/DistrosDefaultLayout#DistrosDefaultLayout-Debian,Ubuntu(Apachehttpd2.x):

```
DocumentRoot            ::      /var/www
```

But my tests show it to be /var/www/html

For example

I'm logged in as root, hence no sudo. I run `apt-get purge apache2` then `apt-get install apache2` then `apt-get autoremove`.

The purge and the install, ensures that I have fresh .conf files. And if DocumentRoot is being explicitly set anywhere then it'd be in .conf files.

I have written an index.html that indicates which directory it is read from

```
root@ubuntu:/# cat /var/www/index.html
in var/www

root@ubuntu:/# cat /var/www/html/index.html
in /var/www/html

root@ubuntu:/#
```

I http to my server from my web browser or run curl and it shows

```
root@ubuntu/# curl 127.0.0.1
in /var/www/html
```

So that isn't /var/www though the documentation says that the default for DocumentRoot is /var/www.

So then I looked at OK maybe it is being explicitly set somewhere so i'll remove anywhere where it's explicitly set.

It mentions these two files.

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2# grep -r 'DocumentRoot' .
./sites-available/000-default.conf:     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
./sites-available/default-ssl.conf:             DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

I understand that apache2.conf loads those 'cos apache2.conf has some "include.." lines, like the line `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`

So I comment out the line in each of those two conf files.

grep confirms those 2 lines are commented out.

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2# grep -r 'DocumentRoot' .
./sites-available/000-default.conf:#    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
./sites-available/default-ssl.conf:#            DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

I think it automatically restarts apache2 when editing files but just incase,

```
root@ubuntu# systemctl restart apache2
root@ubuntu#
```

no errors.

```
root@ubuntu# curl 127.0.0.1
in /var/www/html
```

(or similarly httping with web browser and doing shift-f5 in chrome to make sure it doesn't load from cache  / so for it to check the server). And it says `/var/www/html` )

I was wondering if maybe there was a compile option that mentioned it 'cos I know that apache2 -V can show e.g. the name of the .conf file..  but that doesn't mention any DocumentRoot.

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2# apache2 -V
[Fri Jan 01 01:09:05.977646 2021] [core:warn] [pid 74438:tid 139927292398656] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 16 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2020-08-12T19:46:17
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:88
Server loaded:  APR 1.6.5, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Compiled using: APR 1.6.5, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

As another test, I tried a more minimalistic version of apache2.conf that I made

```
#ServerRoot "/usr/httpd"
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

# LoadModule..........


IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf



DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn


# Port to Listen on
Listen *:80

# In a basic setup httpd can only serve files from its document root
#DocumentRoot "/usr/httpd/htdocs"
#DocumentRoot "/usr/apache2/"

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>


<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

restarted the server just incase that were necessary.

curl 127.0.0.1  still showed `/var/www/html`

Comment: It's also probably set as a compile-time default when building apache

Comment: @muru see in my answer though I did do `apache2 -V` and it doesn't show that compile-time default. Can you show that such a compile-time default exists? Even aside from the fact that the documentation seems to differ with what I found it to be

Comment: Seems to be patched  in: https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/tree/debian/patches/fhs_compliance.patch?h=ubuntu/focal#n62 the problem with the documentation is that you have only linked to upstream documentation. When using a distribution, you also need to check the distro docs, if any

Comment: Thanks Muru, I see ubuntu distro documentation here https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/web-servers-apache mentions /var/www/html.